# can't do a full text index query in cypher with neo4j 2.0 m03

Tags: neo4j

This query used to work in 1.9

```
start parents=node:app_fulltext(Name = 'Temple') return parents;
```

However in 2.0 m3 it doesn't return any results.  However if I put this into the data browser I get results.

```
node:index:app_fulltext:Name:Temple
```

What am I doing wrong, is 2.0 m3 just broken in terms of querying by full text index?

Answer (score 1):

That's not at all expected. Your old indexes should work just fine.

Have you looked through your logs? Did anything unexpected happen during the upgrade?

Comment: Nothing unexpected happened.  The odd thing is if I change the query to app_fulltext("Name:Temple") that works, but not if I use (Name='Temple')